# regex expression that substitutes "\\n" to '\n'

Tags: regex, sed, substitution

I need a regex expression that substitutes `\\n` in a source code written in C to `\n`.

If:

1. it is NOT in a function call.

   Example:

   `func("str", 1, &addrs);  \\n printf("hello");` → `func("str", 1, &addrs);  \n printf("hello");`
2. it is NOT in a string

   Example:

   `"hello"  \\n "there";` → `"hello"  \n "there"`

As to why I have stray `\\n` in my code I don't want to say. I just wanna get rid of them.

Comment: C tag removed. The file being a c source file does not mean you have a question about programming in C

Comment: Your examples are really bad. There is no `\\n` in either a function call nor a string. They are all outside? Please explain what you want more properly.

Comment: Roll back in version control to before the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly something like 
`func("str\\ntest")` should stay as is and not be replaced.

Given that I can't see an option with a regex or sed. 
I think you'll have to do clean by hand or craft something to parse line by line and replace if the \n is outside a string or function call (even that sounds tricky).

Comment: thank you. somebody that understands what i'm asking for. yep, the "\\n" should stay as it is in `func("str\\ntest"`. are you sure it can't be done with regex?? how about perl regex? coz i've seen code in "programming perl" where they use complicated regex with a lot of backreferencing and a bit of evals and such and they can come close to almost being parser themselves. i've heard a lot of text editors out there, that, when set up for a specific language, uses regex to recognize everything syntactically (parentheses, brackets, symbols, keywords) and do the highlighting and stuff

Comment: i don't really wanna go back to reading "programming perl" and spend  probably even 2-3 hours trying to get this to work.

Comment: Well backreferencing could be of some use if you have "enclosing" tags like in html or a bracket pair. But here you wish to do the opposite (match outside the pairs) and I don't think it could be done. If someone has the solution I hope my answer/comment will help. At least it should help you improve your question to show exemples on where it should not be escaped ;)

Comment: ^ your input is very helpful, so thnx for the reply. so then, i'm falling back to the use of a perl script... <not enclosed even at least once in () or "" (using backreferencing), then substitute>. then loop until EOF... might have to go to another forum for this.

Comment: Well indeed you have, I know no method to negate backreferencing ... Sorry, maybe someone else will answer. You can have a try with http://regex101.com/ too

Comment: ^ i'm just glad that dennis ritchie thought of using different enclosing symbols for different parts of the code. or else, there'd be no loopholes.